# How to set a global default font in mIRC?

Tags: fonts, mirc

According to the [mIRC documentation](http://www.mirc.com/faq6.html#section6-13), you can set the font on a per window basis.

I would like to know if it's possible to set it globally, so that any new window that is opened will used that font instead of "Fixedsys 9".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `-z` flag can be used with the `/font` command:

> -z - clears all font settings and sets all windows to the specified font. If no font is specified, all windows are set to default font settings.

So a command like:

```
/font -z -12 Courier
```

should do it.